# Modifying A star routing for a euclidean graph with edge weights as well as distances

Tags: algorithm, optimization, routes, graph-theory, openstreetmap

I'm in the process of writing an application to suggest circular routes over [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data subject to some constraints (the Orienteering Problem). In the innermost loop of the algorithm I'm trialling is a requirement to find the lowest cost path between two given points. Given the layout of the graph (basically [Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory)), the [A star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) algorithm seems to be likely to produce results in the fastest time given the graph. However as well as distances on my edges (representing actual distances on the map), I also have a series of weights (currently scaled from 0.0, least desirable to 1.0, most desirable) indicating how desirable the particular edge (road/path/etc) is, calculated according to some metrics I've devised for my application.

I would like to modify my distances based on these weights. I am aware that the standard A star heuristic relies on the true cost of the path being at least as great as the estimate (based on a euclidean distance between the points). So my first thought was to come up with a scheme where the minimum edge distance is the real distance (for weight 1.0) and the distance is increased as the weight decreases (for instance quadrupling the distance for weight 0.0). Does this seem a sensible approach, or is there a better standard technique for fast routing under these circumstances?

Comment: How do you chose your path ultimately? How does the desireability comes into factor? Do you want the shortest path with highest desireability? Note that the fact that you want "more desireable path" is problematic, since it can be reduced from [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) Which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your approach is the most sane. Apparently I'm working on a similar problem, and I decided to use exactly the same strategy.

The A* algorithm doesn't necessarily rely on "true distances". It's not even about distances, you actually may minimize other physical quantity - the heuristic function should have the same physical units.

For instance, my problem is to minimize the path **time**, whereas the velocity at any given point depends on the location, time, and the chosen direction. My heuristic function is the rough distance (my problem is on the Earth surface, calculating the great circle distance is somewhat pricey) divided by the maximum allowed velocity. That is, it has units of time, and it's interpreted as the most optimistic time to reach the finishing point from the given location.

Comment: It sounds like you're a decent distance ahead of me in research. So it's reassuring to hear that you're having success with this approach. I am, of course, not concerned about the correctness of the approach I outlined (having chosen a method that fits within the framework of A*) - just whether I would still be getting performance benefits from using A* over Dijkstra, given the chosen distance modifications. And also whether I'm missing a trick from the literature. But it sounds like I should give our common approach a go.

Comment: @Alex Wilson: Yes, A* would definitely give a performance advantage over classical Dijkstra. The more close your heuristic function is to the (modified) distance from the given point - the greater is the benifit. However taking the most optimistic distance is also ok. The benfeit would be smaller though, but still it's better than Dijkstra

Comment: @Alex Wilson: P.S. The trick is that although your edges aren't determined solely by geometry, you still may use A* because of one fact: you have a **minimal bound** for the distance between every two points. This enables to define the heuristic function as this minimal bound distance between the given point and the final one. This in turns guarantees the "triangle inequality" - i.e. modifying the point score by such a function will not affect the final route.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant question is:  "what do you actually want to minimize?".  You need to end up with a single "modified distance", so that your pathfinding algorithm can pick the smallest one.

The continued usefulness of the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) depends on exactly how you integrate "desirability" into your routing distance.  A* requires an "[admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic)" which is optimistic:  the heuristic estimate for your "modified distance" must not exceed the actual "modified distance" (otherwise, the path it finds may not actually be optimal...).  One way to ensure that is to make sure that the modified distance is always larger than the original, Euclidean distance for any given step;  then, any A* heuristic admissible to minimize the Euclidean distance will also be admissible to minimize the modified distance.

For example, if you compute `modified_distance = euclidean_distance / desirability_rating` (for `0<desirability_rating<=1`), your `modified_distance` will never be smaller than the `euclidean_distance`: whatever A* heuristic you were using for your unweighted paths will still be optimistic, so it will be usable for A*.  (although, in regions where every path is undesirable, a highly over-optimistic A* heuristic may not improve performance as much as you would like...)

Answer (score 0):

Fast(er) routing can be done with A*. In my own project I see a boost of approx. 4 times faster [compared](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/wiki/Performance) to dijkstra - so, even faster then [bidirectional dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search).

But there are a lot more technics to improve query speed - e.g. introducing shortcuts and running A* on that graph. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29963/9006) is a more detailed answer.